# Access inner value of an object assigned in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, angularjs-scope

I want to console log a value from my object but it returns an undefined value.

```
$scope.sidsamp = [{todoText:'Clean House', done:false}];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
        $scope.sidsamp.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
        $scope.todoInput = "";
        console.log($scope.sidsamp.todoText);
    };
```

I want to display the value of todoText in my console. How can I possibly do that?

Comment: Its an array not an object which is why you can't access it like that

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple..

Because `$scope.sidsamp` is an array so you cannot access directly its value. You can use loop to access it.

**Here is updated code.**

```
$scope.sidsamp = [{todoText:'Clean House', done:false}];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
        $scope.sidsamp.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
        $scope.todoInput = "";
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.sidsamp.length; i++){
           console.log($scope.sidsamp[i].todoText);
        }            
    };
```